# dynamic route in codeigniter don't work

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

i have problem in codeigniter routes.
i want change url from:`http://example.com/test/news_details?id=17` to `http://example.com/test/funy-url-maker` or `http://example.com/funy-url-maker`

i can make $route dynamicly but it don't work.
my code:

```
$route[rawurlencode("'" . str_replace(' ', '-', $string)) . "'"] = "test/news_details?id=" . $id;
```

i print route and all route's will be add perfectly, but when i want to open `http://example.com/test/funy-url-maker` i will be redirect 404 page :(
any idea?

note:
when i use this as static it work perfectly.like:

`$route[rawurlencode('funyNews')] = "test/b_news";`

Comment: please provide how your are defining the `$string` variable

Comment: `require_once (BASEPATH . 'database/DB' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/url_helper' . EXT);
require_once (BASEPATH . 'helpers/text_helper' . EXT);
$db = &DB();
$query = $db -> get('news');
$result = $query -> result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
$route[rawurlencode("'" . str_replace(' ', '-', $row->subject)) . "'"] = "test/news_details?id=" . $row->id;
}` here you are :)

Comment: hey again, seems like they are updating Stack Overflows servers..

Comment: anyway, can you provide me with the `var_dump` results of your `$result` variable?

Comment: there is utf8 character in it (alot) like :[5]=>
  object(stdClass)#15 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "17"
    ["subject"]=>
    string(21) "this is gona be right"
    ["brief"]=>
    string(8) "testing "
    ["message"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["image"]=>
    string(1) "t"
    ["tag"]=>
    string(13) "#ÙÙ†Ø§ÙˆØ±ÛŒ"
  }

Comment: ok, i just wanted to very the format.. so from what I am understanding.. you want your route to look for urls like `http://www.yourhost.com/this-is-gona-be-right` and route them to `http://www.yourhost.com/news_detais?id=17`.. correct?

Comment: no, reverse of it. :) from `http://www.yourhost.com/news_detais?id=17` to `http://www.yourhost.com/this-is-gona-be-right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after all the questions and answers, I think youre looking for something like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($row->subject)));
    $route[$string] = "test/news_details/$row->id";
}
```

and your controller:

```
function news_details($id){
    var_dump($id);
}
```

Comment: hmmm, i think i answer one of your question wrong :(, yes you right  i want my route to look for urls like `http://www.yourhost.com/this-is-gona-be-right` and route them to `http://www.yourhost.com/news_detais?id=17` , at the end i want to see this `http://www.yourhost.com/this-is-gona-be-right` into my url . and i get all of content from `http://www.yourhost.com/news_detais?id=17`

Comment: Well, in that case, this means that you want your route to look for urls like `http://www.yourhost.com/this-is-gona-be-right` and route them to `http://www.yourhost.com/news_detais?id=17`. I will update my answer.

Comment: yes dear friend. tnx so much. i tried it  a lot , but no result given :(

Comment: tnx for your answer but : 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: i think , something wrong with `?id=` because static route will never have problem.

Comment: well that depends on youre `news_details` controller, how is that setup? is it like this `function news_details($id){}` or is it like this `function news_details(){$id = $this->input->get('id')}` ?

Comment: i use method like this:`public function news_details() {
  $data["active"] = "news";
  $id = (int)$_GET["id"];
  $val["result"] = $this -> mydb -> getNewsById($id);
}`

Comment: do you want to see it your self plz?

Comment: i updated my answer. try that out. if not, then maybe I can remotely help you

Comment: sry, still same problem. can you use team viewer to help me  please?

Comment: id:358 910 427    pass:4281